# returning list of lists as dataframe

Tags: r

What is the correct way to record the results of the inner `lapply` call here? My end goal is a dataframe with `percentage_accuracy`, `statparam`, and `cutoff` for each value tested. Is there a more "R" way to do this?

```
best<-lapply(1:100,function(i){
  statval<-sample.int(c(1,0),100,replace=T)
  lapply(1:100,function(j){
    aaa<-statval+j*27 
    list(percentage_accuracy=aaa,statparam=i,cutoff=j)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert the inner most to `data.frame`, `rbind` it and then do the `rbind` on the outer most loop.

```
 d1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(best, function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(x, data.frame) )))
 str(d1)
 #'data.frame':   1000000 obs. of  3 variables:
 #$ percentage_accuracy: num  28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 ...
 #$ statparam          : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 #$ cutoff             : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

---

If this needs to be faster, use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
d2 <- rbindlist(lapply(best, function(x) rbindlist(lapply(x, data.frame))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you're not using [`sample.int()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html) correctly. The first argument is treated as a scalar, representing the number of items to sample from. This means your call is always sampling from one item, namely 1, and there will be no randomness. This differs from the behavior of `sample()`. Example:

```
sample.int(c(1,0),10L,T);
## [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
sample(c(1,0),10L,T);
## [1] 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Given that you need to sample from `0:1`, you should be calling `sample()`.

---

From your code, it looks like we can precompute the `statparam` and `cutoff` columns in one shot without running any loops (hidden or otherwise). We can also precompute a `statval` vector in one shot, after which the only remaining task will be to perform the multiplication and addition to complete the `percentage_accuracy` column. The tricky bit is getting the replications correct, since we need the columns to line up in a particular way, and we need to repeat each 100-element piece of the `statval` vector the correct number of times, since your code reuses it during the inner loop.

Here's how I would do this:

```
set.seed(1L);
NI <- 100L;
NS <- 100L;
NJ <- 100L;
res <- data.frame(
    percentage_accuracy=c(replicate(NI,rep(sample(0:1,NS,T),NJ))),
    statparam=rep(seq_len(NI),each=NS*NJ),
    cutoff=rep(seq_len(NJ),NI,each=NS)
);
res$percentage_accuracy <- res$percentage_accuracy+res$cutoff*27L;
str(res);
## 'data.frame': 1000000 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ percentage_accuracy: int  27 27 28 28 27 28 28 28 28 27 ...
##  $ statparam          : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ cutoff             : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```